# I want to use universal link in my app for two different XCode schemes

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

My project has one target with two schemes. One for production and one for staging.
Each scheme has a different app ID.
I have two websites, one for production and one for staging.
I've supplied two separate apple-app-site-association files for each domain with unique content, and I added each one of them to my websites.
In my associated domains I added both domains.
When I tap a universal link to my production app, it works, and when I tap a universal link to my staging app it doesn't.
Why??

Comment: Use this website https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ to validate your websites are setup correct. If that looks good, then please post your `apple-app-site-association` file along with additional information about how your schemes are setup.

Comment: My AASA for staging is: 
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TEAM_ID.BUNDLE_ID",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}

and for production: 
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TEAM_ID.BUNDLE_ID",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Each scheme has a different bundle id.
I have one target for both.
I configured different associated domains for each scheme, using user defined settings.
Notice that when I compiled production, the universal link works, and after compiling staging both production and staging universal links don't work. (Like staging compilation overrides something..)